# Setting and getting Excel cell value in Applescript

Tags: applescript

I seem not to be able to access a cell or a range using column and row number in Excel via Applescript.

Minimal example:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    -- works
    log range (get address row 1, column 1) of sheet 1 of active workbook
    -- fails
    set r to (range (get address row 1, column 1) of sheet 1 of active workbook)
end tell
```

Why does

```
log range (get address row 1, column 1) of sheet 1 of active workbook
```

work while

```
set r to (range (get address row 1, column 1) of sheet 1 of active workbook)
```

fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `log` command works because it is doing something very different than the `set` command is attempting to do.

The `set` command is trying to set a variable to the results of an invalid statement. The result is an error.

```
error "Microsoft Excel got an error: The object you are ¬
trying to access does not exist" number -1728 from range ¬
    {"$1:$1", column "$A:$A"} of sheet 1 of active workbook
```

If you remove the commands from in front of the statement you will get the same error.

```
(range {get address row 1, column 1} of sheet 1 of active workbook)
```

The key part is this below, which is not a valid range. Instead, it is an attempt to make a list containing two separate items (a string and a column) into a range object:

```
range {"$1:$1", column "$A:$A"}
```

What `log` is doing is more passive. This is from the [Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW49)

> The value to display. Expressions are evaluated but object specifiers are not resolved.

The object specifier in this case is the *range* but it cannot be resolved as the syntax is incorrect. Therefore, `log` shows the bits and pieces but `set` fails.

If you wish to have a single range that includes all of row 1 and all of column A, then this would work:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set rowRange to range "1:1"
    set colRange to range "A:A"
    
    set r to union range1 rowRange range2 colRange
    --> range "[Workbook1]Sheet1!$1:$1,$A:$A" of application "Microsoft Excel"
    select r
end tell
```

and instead to get the single cell at the intersection you can do:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set rowRange to range "1:1"
    set colRange to range "A:A"
    
    set r to intersection range1 rowRange range2 colRange
    select r
end tell
```

You could also mimic the syntax of the result:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    set r to range "[Workbook1]Sheet1!$1:$1,$A:$A"
end tell

-- OR

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet of workbook 1 
        set r to range "$1:$1,$A:$A"        
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I didn't know about union, and via that I discovered intersect too. I added an example about that too, I hope you don't mind. Great, thorough explanation

Comment: It's a good addition. I think that `union` and `intersect` are really useful commands and as you suggest, they go hand-in-hand.